# What are the exact steps to integrate sonarqube with bitbucket?

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, bitbucket

What I've done so far:

1) I am using TeamCity as the CI.

2) Already have a SonarQube server up and running.

3) Already have a Bitbucket account.

4) I put the sonar-bitbucket-plugin-1.2.0.jar file in the /extensions/plugins folder. Restarted the sonarqube server afterwards

5) I added a sonar.json file to each module of the project containing the following:

```
{   
    "sonarHost": "<sonarqube server ip address>",
    "sonarProjectKey": "<sonarProjectKey taken from sonar host>"
}
```

6) Installed the sonar for bitbucket plugin.

7) I created a consumer in the OAath section of Bitbucket Settings, with permissions specified in the github bitbucket plugin project (https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin), in order to collect key and secret codes.

8) I executed the following command on one of the modules of the repository:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar --batch-mode --errors -Dsonar.bitbucket.repoSlug="<repoSlug>" -Dsonar.bitbucket.accountName="<accountName>"-Dsonar.bitbucket.apiKey="<apiKey>" -Dsonar.bitbucket.branchName="<branchName>" -Dsonar.host.url="<serverUrl>" -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues
```

The sonar analysis runs smoothly, but after getting to the bitbucket bit, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project dispatcher: Unable to load component class ch.mibex.bitbucket.sonar.client.BitbucketClient: [sonar4bitbucket] Either team-based API or an OAuth user must be given -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project dispatcher: Unable to load component class ch.mibex.bitbucket.sonar.client.BitbucketClient
```

For the apiKey property, I used either the key or secret codes from the OAuth consumer.

**What am I missing ?**

Comment: Did you include a [User Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token)?

Comment: What is your OAuth consumer's call back URL ?